# How the byte range is -128 to 127 in java.How it is possible?

Tags: java, byte

1 byte = 8bits

I converted  `1111 1111` binary number to decimal .it is giving me `255`.

But when i  converted  `0111 1111` binaru number to decimal .it is giving me `127`.

So on what basis the range is declared.Please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. 127 + 2**7 = 255.

Comment: byte is signed(both positive and negative) in java.And its from -128 to 127.

Comment: It is -128 to +127, not -127 to +128.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number types in Java are signed, meaning they can be negative or positive. The leftmost bit (the [most significant bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit)) is used to represent the sign, where a `1` means negative and `0` means positive.

**Byte**

```
Max 01111111  = +127
Min 10000000  = -128

    11111111  = -1
```

**Short**

```
Max 0111111111111111  = +32767
Min 1000000000000000  = -32768

    0000000011111111  = +255
```

Binary negative numbers are represented in [2's complement form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: if left most bit is for sign then 10000000   values is 0?

Comment: incase of negative number ,left most bit is 1 which does two work i.e tell number is negative and also calculates as 128. see my answer below

Comment: `10000000 = -128` because of Two's complement

Comment: How -128 will come.Can u explain pls

Comment: i see in the link they give -128 for 10000000.How it is possible

Answer (score 2):

One bit is reserved for detrmining whether number is negative or positive .

So for max postive number value will be

```
 01111111 which gives the int number as 128(leftmost bit 0 represent its a postive number)

        64+32+6+8+4+2+1= 127
```

for max negativenumber value will ((leftmost bit 1 represent its a negative number))

```
  10000000 which gives the int number as -128

  -128+0+0+0+0+0+0+0 = -128
```

so range becomes from

```
  -127 to 128
```